# How to modify blended video durations with a -filter_complex command argument in ffmpeg

Tags: command-line, command, video, ffmpeg, video-editing

Building off the solution provided [in this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499573/how-to-transition-smoothly-and-repeatedly-between-two-videos-using-command-line), I'd like to know how to make simple modifications to a complex command argument which uses ffmpeg to interweave two videos by dissolving them into each other every 2 seconds, with a 0.5 second transition. It looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mkv -i input2.mkv -filter_complex \
       "[0][1]blend=all_expr='if(mod(trunc(T/2),2),min(1,2*(T-2*trunc(T/2))),max(0,1-2*(T-2*trunc(T/2))))*A+if(mod(trunc(T/2),2),max(0,1-2*(T-2*trunc(T/2))),min(1,2*(T-2*trunc(T/2))))*B';\
        [0]volume='if(mod(trunc(t/2),2),min(1,2*(t-2*trunc(t/2))),max(0,1-2*(t-2*trunc(t/2))))':eval=frame[a]; [1]volume='if(mod(trunc(t/2),2),max(0,1-2*(t-2*trunc(t/2))),min(1,2*(t-2*trunc(t/2))))':eval=frame[b];\
        [a][b]amix" output.mkv
```

It works beautifully for its intended purpose, however this is some serious command line magic and I can't understand how to change the cut up duration or transition duration.

Suppose I want a 3 sec cut up w/ a 1 sec transition, or a 1 sec cut-up w/ a 0.25 sec transition, what parts of this command would I alter to achieve that? What specific variables do I change?

Comment: As a first step it would probably help to format the `filter_complex` argument into multiple lines so it's more readable.

Comment: I'll add a generic version to my earlier answer soon-ish.

Comment: @gyan Could you define "soon-ish"? I believe you might be the only one able to answer this question. No rush or anything, I do appreciate your help on this.

Comment: By weekend, I hope.