# How to increase the duration of the transition effect between multiple video cuts in this ffmpeg `-filter_complex` command

Tags: command-line, scripting, video, ffmpeg

As instructed in Gyan's solution to this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499573/how-to-transition-smoothly-and-repeatedly-between-two-videos-using-command-line), ffmpeg can be used to interleave two audio/video inputs with a lapse dissolve transition. For example, this command will divide each input into cut ups of 6 seconds and introduce a smooth alternating 0.5 second fade in/out between the two:

`ffmpeg -i input1.mkv -i input2.mkv -filter_complex "[0][1]blend=all_expr='if(mod(trunc(T/6),2),min(1,2*(T-6*trunc(T/6))),max(0,1-2*(T-6*trunc(T/6))))*A+if(mod(trunc(T/6),2),max(0,1-2*(T-6*trunc(T/6))),min(1,2*(T-6*trunc(T/6))))*B';[0]volume='if(mod(trunc(t/6),2),min(1,2*(t-6*trunc(t/6))),max(0,1-2*(t-6*trunc(t/6))))':eval=frame[a]; [1]volume='if(mod(trunc(t/6),2),max(0,1-2*(t-6*trunc(t/6))),min(1,2*(t-6*trunc(t/6))))':eval=frame[b];[a][b]amix" output.mkv`

(A similar command is in an easier to read format at the original question.)

I found I could change the duration of the video cut ups by changing the `6` variable in the above command. What I don't know is how to increase the duration of the transition effect. The command at issue doesn't use the `fade` video filter, but a more obtuse mathematical formulation.

I've read the manual, tested many variables in the command, and also asked a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503554/how-to-modify-blended-video-durations-with-a-filter-complex-command-argument-in) several months ago. How do I increase the duration of the transition effect between multiple video cuts in the above ffmpeg `-filter_complex` command?